# Green's Theorem problem over a quadrangle...

Tags: calculus

Use Green’s theorem to evaluate the integral
\begin{equation*}
\int_{C} (6y-9x) \; dy - \left(yx-x^3\right) \; dx,
\end{equation*}
where $C$ is the quadrangle with vertices $(1,-1)$, $(1,1)$, $(-1,3)$ and $(-1,-1)$, and the positive orientation.
Well we have $P = -(yx-x^3)$ and $Q = 6y-9x$ so $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = -x$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = -9$. This means (using Green's theorem)
\begin{equation*}
\int_{C} (6y-9x) \; dy - \left(yx-x^3\right) \; dx = \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{-x+2} (x-9) \; dy \; dx.
\end{equation*}
Is this correct? Thanks!!!

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Change -x+2 by 3 in the limits of integration.

Comment: What do you mean change $-x+2$ by $3$?

Comment: I get $-164/3$.